# class and object base API operation block/closure advantages and disadvantages

Tags: objective-c, swift, asynchronous, closures, block

I have one class and I need to write one block/closure which will do following tasks.

1. Get data from from server (via **asynchronous** API call).
2. Convert response in my one class object.
3. Add those object in one Array.
4. Return that array to block/closure.

so my question is which type of block will write, is it **CLASS** type or **OBJECT** type (like +/- methods in objective-C ) and **why**? **(advantages and disadvantages of it respectively)**

Need to brief explaination.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What *is* "CLASS type of OBJECT type"? What do either of those terms mean (to you)?

Comment: sorry for inconvenience please check updated question